# jxbrowser loads old license even after uploading a new license in Netbeans

Tags: jxbrowser

I am trying to run an application on Netbeans, but when i try to run jxbrowser, it gives me an error saying license has been expired.

Tried re installing netbeans, clearing cache and still nothing works.

xBrowser license check failed: No valid license found. jar:file:/C:/Users/purva/OneDrive/Desktop/New%20Libs/license.jar!/META-INF/teamdev.licenses - Your evaluation period ended on 2018-01-02. For more details, please visit https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/evaluation-period-termination
java.lang.RuntimeException: JxBrowser license check failed: No valid license found. jar:file:/C:/Users/purva/OneDrive/Desktop/New%20Libs/license.jar!/META-INF/teamdev.licenses - Your evaluation period ended on 2018-01-02. For more details, please visit https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/evaluation-period-termination

Gives the following error.

Even though i have added a new valid license in my library and deleted the old one, it still picks up the old license date.
My new license is valid until 15-05-2019 but it take the old licence and throws that error.

Answer (score 0):

The trial license works for 30 days only. The newly downloaded evaluation license will not activate this period again. Please contact TeamDev directly to help you with this matter.